# Iteration of the construction of Cevian triangles

Tags: triangles

[image: Generic Cevian]

Pick some [triangle center](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html). Construct the Cevian triangle. Consider its angles. If you want to iterate the construction (find the same triangle center for the Cevian triangle, and so on), the angles $\phi,\dots$ of the Cevian triangle should be a simple function of the reference triangle, say $\phi=\lambda*\alpha+\mu*\pi$ (and analogous for $\beta,\gamma$), with $\lambda\in\{0,1,-1,2,-2,1/2,-1/2\}$ for starters. The other angle $\psi$ isn't good for iteration, but I threw it in since it also makes for some interesting centers (this obviously is a totally different problem).

I made a screenshot of a table with some obvious center entries. (Sorry, I am lousy at TeX formatting.) If I still had MATHEMATICA, I would fill the blanks myself by simply computing the center values and looking it up in the above link. But I haven't, such are the risks of graduating :-) Can you help me identifying the missing centers? The first missing I "found" myself eons ago but long forgot its official name...

EDIT: Some (partly glaring obvious) additions and corrections, one center definitely is new (y given). ?: No idea how to define those angles for obtuse triangles.

[image: Corrections]

Comment: I advise you to use Geogebra : it provides you the possibility to directly use a triangle center you want (with its identifier number from the ETC). For example, if you write H=TriangleCentre(A,B,C,4) you will get the orthocentre (which is X(4)) of triangle $A,B,C$

Comment: @JeanMarie: THX for the tip; BTW, ETC mostly uses "Geometers Sketchpad". Never had the time to try it out these things yet...

Answer (score 1):

Half an answer, which I only "accidentally" found in the 40000s of the ETC:
The part with the central angles $\psi$ is know as the concept "$t$-central angle point" (duuuuh :-) - the connection is $t=2/3*\lambda+4/3$; excluding the one I already mentioned there are (as $t$, center):

(-2,5964)

(4,5963)

(-1,41622)

(3,42621)

(-2/3,42619)

(8/3,42620)

(1/3,42615)

(5/3,42616)

(1/2,42618)

(3/2,42614)

thus this half of the question can be closed (further $\lambda$ might be added ad lib; it would be interesting how the -clearly transcendent- curve of all these centers looks - EDIT: have a look at curve of the usual $6-9-13$ triangle.)

[image: transcendent curve]

Comment: Note that the ETC list has a bug: 42617 is amiss in the above list (which I only copypasted from the definition paragraph), to be congruent with the actual point list subtract 1 from all>42617!